# Wrap output of a function in a new datatype

Tags: haskell, typeclass, coercion

I have a function `a -> [b]`, and I am looking for a function to transform it into a similar function, but with elements of the list being wrapped in some newtype/data: `a -> [t b]`. So I need to find a function, that does the following: **`(a -> [b]) -> (a -> [t b])`**.

Hoogle gives `traverse` as the closest match, but it is not exactly what I am looking for. Is there any way to construct the function, that I need, using Haskell's powerful typeclasses?

Without that I can manage, but the code will have to be more verbose like `Boardable <$> makeBListFrom a`, where `Boardable` constructor stands for `t`.

Comment: I don't think there is anything specifically geared for that purpose. My only suggestion is that the pointfree spelling of what you suggest in the last paragraph is arguably a bit neater: `fmap Boardable . makeBListFrom`

Comment: Yes! Exactly. That's what I mean. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a `newtype`, you are looking for [**`coerce`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Coerce.html) (since from a runtime perspective, the conversion `a -> [b]` to `a -> [t b]` is a no-op). Of course, this will only work if Haskell is able to infer the type you are trying to coerce to.

You get `coerce makeBListFrom :: A -> [Boardable B]` (where `A` and `B` are some types determined from `makeBListFrom :: A -> [B]`).

---

This will *not* work for `data`. Also, if it were me, I would stick to `fmap Boardable . makeBListFrom` - your intentions are clearer to both the compiler and a reader (either of these will be able to synthesize a type, instead of having to check against one).

Comment: Yes. Thank you for the input.
I am with `data` and moreover it is `ExistentialQuantification` wrapper. So, yes. `fmap` is the key.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just `map` the constructor over each element?

```
Prelude> data X a = C a deriving Show
Prelude> map C [1, 2, 3]
[C 1,C 2,C 3]
Prelude> :t map C [1, 2, 3]
map C [1, 2, 3] :: Num a => [X a]
```

Comment: The OP is already doing that through `(<$>)` (cf. the final paragraph of the question).

Comment: I assumed that they were looking for an operator that behaves like `Boardable <$>`, which `map C` satisfies. Maybe I was reading into the question too much.

Comment: Yes. `map` or `fmap` or `<$>` is clearly possible. But that's what I call _verbose_. Right now I am with that.
What I am looking for is for some smart way **not** to give the actual list to the `map`, but to transform the function as it is.

Comment: @Dahan, I'm still not clear.  Transform the function as it is... is `(map C .) :: (a -> [b]) -> (a -> [C b])` not precisely the transformation you are seeking? Is your requirement for non-verbosity that it is spelled with a single word?  Or is that you don't want to mention `C`?

Comment: That's fine. `map C .` does the thing. I was just reading typeclassopedia and was under it's influence, thinking, that everything should be much more magical, than it is ))